# Get row count if excel sheet has data in a row

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an Excel sheet where it has 14 rows. 2 of the rows are empty. Out of 14 rows there are 12 rows where it has data. Data may exist in any of the column of each row. So I want to iterate each row's cell and if data is present in any of the cells, then I need to increment the `j` variable .

My requirement is that if there are 14 rows and out of which 12 rows have data then `j` variable should print 12 .

```
package com.optum.synergy.nav4Me.ui.stepDefinitions;

import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellAddress;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ExcelSheetTest {
    public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "C:/Users/abc/Documents/excel_test.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("okkk");
        // Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)
        Workbook workbook;
        try {
            workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));
            System.out.println("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets  ");
            Sheet sh = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            int num1 = sh.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            System.out.println(" " + num1);
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {

                Row eachrow = sh.getRow(i);
                for (Cell cell : eachrow) {
                    System.out.println("...... "+cell);
                    if(cell !=null){
                        j++ ;
                        break ;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Row counts :"+j);

        } catch (EncryptedDocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Retrieving the number of sheets in the Workbook

    }

}
```

Currently "Row Counts :" printing : 14

How should I fix the code to fulfil my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if(cell !=null && cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
{
j++ ;
break ;
}
```

Comment: Still i am getting 
Row counts :14

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are different kinds of empty cells: the once with no data and the once with an empty string as the data. Maybe that is what cases you problem?

Try checking for an empty string in the cell value:

```
// I think this check will handle blank cells also
if (cell != null && !cell.toString().isEmpty()) {
    j++;
    break;
}
```